What's the gain from multistate model comparing to transition specific survival models?
Currently I'm working on multistate patient data, where patient transitions into states are observed at exact, irregular occasions. However discharge times from the states are unknown. Patients can come back to a state that they've already been. I've tried to use msm package from R, unfortunately I can't get convergence no matter what (even without covariates). It happens probably due to insufficient transitions to some states. Someone told me to go for transition-specific Cox models. I never thought about it but what's the true gain of using one multistate model compared to couple transition-specific Cox models?

Just speaking in general, there are major advantages of doing unified vs. separate analyses in such settings.  One of the biggest advantages is that you can estimate unconditional quantities in a multistate transition model.  For example if there are outcomes 1, 2, 3, one can estimate for a given follow-up time P(1 occurs), P(1 or 2 occurs), P(1 occurs but not 2), etc.  In health studies this is very relevant.  For example we may want to estimate the probability of being alive and well, P(dead), P(dead or unwell) as of specific times.
